# Switch statement instead of multiple nested if - else?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, nested-if

I've come across a situation where I have a bunch of "systems" that need to be initialized in sequence, with the next system only being initialized if all of the proceeding systems initialized successfully.

This has led me to a whole slew of nested if - else statements. Here's some pseudo-code for visualization.

```
bool mainInit () {
    if (!system1Init ()) {
        reportError ();  // some error reporting function
    }
    else {
        if (!system2Init ()) {
            reportError ();
        }
        else {
            if (!system3Init ()) {
            // ... and so on
```

I find that this starts to look like a mess when you get even a handful of levels to it.

Now I thought of using a switch statement instead, starting at the first case and falling through to the other cases on success, only breaking if there's an error.

```
bool mainInit () {

    switch (1) {
    case 1:
        if (!system1Init ()) {
            reportError ();
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        if (!system2Init ())
            reportError ();
            break;
        }
    // ....
}
```

Now, I like this a lot better.  I find it much easier to read, especially with some decent comments, but I'm fairly new to programming.

So, my question is: Seeing how this is not how switch statements are traditionally used(at least from what I've seen), is something like this acceptable, or would this be considered bad form?

Being new to programming, I'm trying not to develop too many bad habits that might frustrate and make things more difficult for other programmers down the road.

I did a search, but most of what I found had to do with replacing chains of if - else if statements, not replacing nested ones.

Comment: What comes after all of the if-statements? What does `mainInit` return?

Comment: How about `return false` or `throw ...` on failure?

Comment: You don't have to do `else { if() {` most people do `else if() {`.

Comment: @Beta sorry, it returns true if all systems initialize successfully, and false if there's any failures

Answer (score 3):

Reference all of the systems in an array, for example an `std::vector<mySystem*>`, and loop over them sequentially, breaking off on the first fail. This way your entire code is reduced to less than 5 lines of code, even for 500+ systems.

The suggested switch hack is an evil example of [XY problem solving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/219504): your real problem is that you don't have the array of systems, and are using named variables, thus eliminating all options to more flexibly use all systems, like in a loop.

Comment: I made a mistake in the code in my question, I'm not handling system objects directly(I'm not even sure if there's an object underneath it all) I'm initializing parts of a c library for use. I apologize. I guess I didn't really understand what it was I should be asking.  So would I use a vector of function* then?

Comment: I do not think that question was an XY problem since the user ask the right question first and gave a possible answer of what he was thinking he could do. XY is when the user only asks "should I do a switch" without first stating the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your `system#Init()` calls are known at compile time, you can very easily put them in a table and then iterate over that table.

```
typedef (*system_init)(void);

system_init initialization_functions[] =
{
    system1Init,
    system2Init,
    system3Init,
      ...
    systemNInit
};

bool mainInit()
{
    for(size_t idx(0); idx < sizeof(initialization_functions) / sizeof(initialization_functions[0]); ++idx)
    {
        if(!initialization_functions[idx]())
        {
            ReportError();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, your existing code looks incorrect since the first `mainInit()` only calls `system1Init()` and then exits. Probably not what you wanted in the first place.

```
if(!system1Init())
{
    ReportError();
    return false;
}
// if you add an else, the system2Init() does not get called
// even if system1Init() succeeds
if(!system2Init())
{
    ReportError();
    return false;
}
[...]
return true;
```

Would the switch answer your problem? Not as it was written. That is, if you wanted to call the `mainInit()` function with a counter, it could be useful. Drupal uses that mechanism:

```
bool mainInit(int idx)
{
    bool r(true);
    switch(idx)
    {
    case 1:
        r = system1Init();
        break;

    case 2:
        r = system2Init();
        break;

    [...]
    }
    if(!r)
    {
        ReportError();
    }
    return r
}
```

Note that the table mechanism works the same way as the switch. As long as all the code is found in the `systemNInit()` functions (and it should be), the switch does not add anything, so you could do something like this too:

```
bool mainInit(int idx)
{
    if(idx < 0 || idx >= sizeof(initialization_functions) / sizeof(initialization_functions[0]))
    {
        throw std::range_error("index out of bounds");
    }
    if(!initialization_functions[idx]())
    {
        ReportError();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Calling the `mainInit()` with an index can be helpful in case you want to "de-initialize" properly:

```
int main()
{
    for(size_t idx(0); idx < ...; ++idx)
    {
        if(!mainInit(idx))
        {
            while(idx > 0)
            {
                --idx;
                mainDeinit(idx);
            }
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    ...app do something here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom exceptions with clear error messages and add a try-catch-report-die around the code in `main()`. Exceptions are there to specifically make your case look good by making "bad path" implicit.

```
void initX() { ...; throw std::invalid_argument_exception("..."); }

int main() {
    try {
        init1(); init2(); ... run();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        log(e.what()); exit 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
bool mainInit () {
  if (!system1Init ()) {
    return(false);
  }

  if (!system2Init ()) {
    return(false);
  }

  if (!system3Init ()) {
    return(false);
  }

  //...                 

  return(true);
}

//...

if(!mainInit()) {
  reportError();
}
```